# Porting Chrome extension using jQuery to Firefox SDK Add-on

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, require, commonjs

My Chrome extension makes use of jQuery in the background page, for things like `jQuery.extend()`, `jQuery.ajax()`, `jQuery.deferred()`, (not DOM manipulation stuff, which doesn't make sense in a background page).

Migrating this code to a [Firefox SDK Add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Add-ons/SDK), there's no background `window` object, which jQuery requires to work, so something like

```
var $ = require('../3rdparty/jquery.min')(window);
```

which is how jQuery works in a CommonJS-like environment, fails, with jQuery itself throwing a `jQuery requires a window with a document` exception.

Is there any way to use jQuery in a Firefox SDK-based add-on? [Page Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker) seemed promising, but I can't get hold of the underlying `window` object.

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
    var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
    _window = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/appShellService;1"]
        .getService(Ci.nsIAppShellService).‌​hiddenDOMWindow;

    $ = require('../3rdparty/jquery')(_window);
```

However, I had to patch jQuery (2.1.3) itself, changing line 3441 to

```
    window.setTimeout( jQuery.ready );
```

I'm reasonably confident this is a jQuery bug.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andy! It seems to be working beautifully!

When I read that you had to hack jQuery a bit, I set out to submit a fix but it turned out that somebody did just that already!

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/842958e7aecd0d75a7ee9e2aaec83457701aa2f3

It's been shipped in jQuery 3.0.0-alpha1 though.